# Magento how to re-index product prices pro-grammatically

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I am trying to re-index product prices after update in my product price but its not working showing me old price in product list page.I am using this code

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

i also tried this one

```
$reindex = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
$reindex ->reindexAll();
```

But its not working. I have tried from by this command

> php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price

Its working fine showing me updated prices.

Comment: What does `$reindex` contain? Are you sure it is loaded?

Comment: yeah 2 is the id of this process catalog_product_price

Comment: I know, but I asked it you are sure `$reindex` is a loaded object or not. Try echoing `echo $reindex->getStatus()` and see it if works.

Comment: string(7) "pending" getting this

Comment: Have you tried running `$reindex->reindexEverything()` ?

Comment: i don't want to reindex everything its taking too much time i

Answer (score 1):

The right function to call is:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($ids);
```

Just add it in an observer.

Answer (score 1):

Create external file **test.php** in magento root. Please add below code in it.

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// clear cache
Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');

// reindex prices
Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2)->reindexEverything();
/*
1 = Product Attributes
2 = Product Attributes
3 = Catalog URL Rewrites
4 = Product Flat Data
5 = Category Flat Data
6 = Category Products
7 = Catalog Search Index
8 = Tag Aggregation Data
9 = Stock Status
*/

// Recreate a single index programmatically
Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Flat::CATALOG_FLAT_PROCESS_CODE, 'indexer_code')->reindexEverything();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could build a custom script to run `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price` as a crontab (if you're using Linux).

It's not a magento solution, but it would work if it's something that's mission critical. Where you could have it run on a regular interval? Not the best solution, but it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The OP wants to do it programmatically, not using the command line.

Comment: How is that not programmatically?